# Find old display names of a user

Tags: app, users, website

As [observed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116801/259867), it can be

> confusing when certain users who had gone months under one name suddenly switched to new names

So I've made a simple API-based tool:

#### [Old display names of a user](http://normalhuman.github.io/oldusernames/)

It is based on `/users/{ids}/mentioned` method of Stack Exchange API, which returns all comments in which the user was mentioned. Usernames are extracted and presented in chronological order, with links to comments in case further inspection is needed. There are inevitable spelling variations, as well as occasional false matches (such as "Community" in the screenshot below: it came from a comment by which I was pinged because of being the sole previous commentator.).

I advise against running this for the most active users on Stack Overflow: it will likely drain the API quota. (The script stops when exhausting the quota, and respects backoff should it be received.)

The [source is here](https://github.com/normalhuman/normalhuman.github.io/tree/master/oldusernames). The license is [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/).

[image]

Comment: That script is cool, but it has a bug. In one comment was a android xml reference which resulted that I had the nickname style, very funny.

Comment: This tool is no longer active. :(

Comment: As the link is no longer working, I have tried to get working version from the bits I saw in Wayback Machine - I have put it on my website: http://msleziak.com/stackexchange/oldusernames/ I posted more details on MathOverflow Meta: [Recognizing identifiable users changing user names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4426#4427) This tool was also mentioned in this answer on Meta Stack Exchange: [Make the “past names” list public info for 30 days after changing your name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116801#252051).